# Отель-легенда: через дефис или через тире? Знак меняет смысл?

Tags: пунктуация, дефис-тире

> Очевидно же, что крохотные, умирающие городки не в состоянии
>   предложить столичному жителю ничего качественного. Есть отели –
>   легенды, это правда. Но в Ферраре их нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Очевидно же, что крохотные, умирающие городки не в состоянии
>   предложить столичному жителю ничего качественного. Есть отели –
>   легенды, это правда. Но в Ферраре их нет.

Дефис и тире - совершенно разные знаки: дефис предназначен для соединения частей одного слова;
тире призвано разделять два слова (если слово проговаривается, то на месте тире должна последовать небольшая пауза).

Поэтому смысл, конечно, меняется. Нужно хорошо себе представлять, чем является слово легенда. Оно нарицательное, одиночное. Если это приложение, то однозначно пишется через дефис с определяемым словом.Тире могло бы быть перед неоднословными приложениями: творчество поэтов – современников Пушкина; о Маршаке – переводчике Шекспира; печальная судьба дома – памятника архитектуры; среди стран – участников переговоров.

У нас *отель-легенда.* Два нарицательных существительных,  приложение обозначает неотъемлемый признак высокого качества (легенда = мечта), как в примерах Лопатина: город-герой, зима-волшебница, царевна-лягушка, внук-шофёр, проказница-мартышка, птица-песня, француз-учитель.

Если же это тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, то сама фраза должна бы звучать по-другому: Такие отели – легенды, это правда.

Так что здесь, я думаю, всё-таки дефис при одиночном приложении.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Вариант с тире**

Я бы остановилась на варианте с обособленным приложением: ***Есть отЕли – легЕвды, это правда. Но в Ферраре их нет.***  Смысл такой: есть отели, которые считаются легендами, но в Ферраре их нет.

Здесь ***легенды*** можно считать присоединительным членом предложения, обособленным тире. Эта конструкция не такая стандартная, как при дефисном написании, **но утверждать, что ее не существует, было бы неверно.** Её существование подтверждается интонацией, которая совершенно не совпадет с дефисным вариантом.

Здесь ударение падает и на существительное,  и на обособленное приложение, делается **пауза.**

2) **Вариант с дефисным написанием**

Есть отели-легЕнды. Произношение без паузы (в одно слово) и с одним ударением.

Эта фраза подходит в качестве вступления для рассказа о таких отелях: Существуют *отели, которые можно назвать легендами.* К таким *отелям-легендам* относится отель...

**Так что выбор есть.**  Нельзя сказать, что здесь разный смысл, но **грамматические конструкции разные.** И каждый вариант подходит для определенного текста.